# Android Studio - Gradle sync failed: Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host

Tags: android-studio, gradle, synchronization

In my home computer, Android Studio works fine, but in my office PC it, since I have updated to Android Studio 4.1.1 it gives me always next error when it starts and syncs:  "established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine".

I have uninstalled Android Studio, clearing user data and reinstalled it again, but the error remains.

I use a default Android project (create new and compile it, ok in home, this error in office)

The idea.log file shows next information:

```
2020-11-18 10:40:16,856 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2020-11-18 10:40:16,872 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283, 05 Nov 2020 03:41) 
2020-11-18 10:40:16,872 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 10 (10.0, amd64) 
2020-11-18 10:40:16,872 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 (JetBrains s.r.o) 
2020-11-18 10:40:16,872 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.242-b01 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2020-11-18 10:40:16,872 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: exit -Xms256m -Xmx1280m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Didea.vendor.name=Google -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe.vmoptions -Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin\server -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.jre.check=true -Dide.native.launcher=true -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio4.1 -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\jiroldan\java_error_in_studio_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\jiroldan\java_error_in_studio.hprof 
2020-11-18 10:40:16,872 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\ext: [access-bridge-64.jar, cldrdata.jar, dnsns.jar, jaccess.jar, localedata.jar, meta-index, nashorn.jar, sunec.jar, sunjce_provider.jar, sunmscapi.jar, sunpkcs11.jar, zipfs.jar] 
2020-11-18 10:40:16,872 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - library path: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin\server 
2020-11-18 10:40:16,872 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - boot library path: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin 
2020-11-18 10:40:16,872 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Locale=es_ES JNU=Cp1252 file.encoding=Cp1252 
2020-11-18 10:40:16,957 [    101]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 85 ms 
2020-11-18 10:40:17,026 [    170]   INFO - ntellij.idea.ApplicationLoader - CPU cores: 8; ForkJoinPool.commonPool: java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@78f933d6[Running, parallelism = 7, size = 0, active = 0, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 0, submissions = 0]; factory: com.intellij.concurrency.IdeaForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory@5f5e8957 
2020-11-18 10:40:17,188 [    332]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2020-11-18 10:40:17,427 [    571]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin org.intellij.groovy misses optional descriptor duplicates-groovy.xml 
2020-11-18 10:40:17,427 [    571]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin org.intellij.groovy misses optional descriptor duplicates-detection-groovy.xml 
2020-11-18 10:40:17,527 [    671]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin com.intellij.java misses optional descriptor profiler-java.xml 
2020-11-18 10:40:17,605 [    749]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: IDEA CORE (201.8743.12), com.intellij.platform.images (201.8743.12.41.6953283), JetBrains Repository Search (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Subversion (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Smali Support (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Configuration Script (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Copyright (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Java (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Git (201.8743.12.41.6953283), ChangeReminder (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Next File Prediction (201.8743.12.41.6953283), JUnit (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Layoutlib Native (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Layoutlib Standard (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Google Login (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Java IDE Customization (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Task Management (201.8743.12.41.6953283), GitHub (201.8743.12.41.6953283), IntelliLang (201.8743.12.41.6953283), TestNG (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Code Coverage for Java (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Java Stream Debugger (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Java Bytecode Decompiler (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Gradle (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Properties (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Java Internationalization (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Groovy (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Gradle-Java (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Kotlin (1.3.72-release-Studio4.1-5), Compose (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Google Cloud Tools Core (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Resource Bundle Editor (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Mercurial (201.8743.12.41.6953283), EditorConfig (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Terminal (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Android (10.4.1.1), Android NDK Support (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Android APK Support (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Google Developers Samples (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Test Recorder (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Firebase Services (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Firebase Testing (201.8743.12.41.6953283), App Links Assistant (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Firebase App Indexing (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Shell Script (201.8743.12.41.6953283), TextMate bundles (201.8743.12.41.6953283), YAML (201.8743.12.41.6953283), Settings Repository (201.8743.12.41.6953283) 
2020-11-18 10:40:22,258 [   5402]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=1217 
2020-11-18 10:40:22,274 [   5418]   INFO - tellij.util.io.FileChannelUtil - interruptible FileChannel-s will be used for indexes 
2020-11-18 10:40:22,274 [   5418]   INFO - tellij.util.io.FileChannelUtil - interruptible FileChannel-s will be used for indexes 
2020-11-18 10:40:22,337 [   5481]   INFO - cation.options.RegistryManager - Registry values changed by user: external.system.auto.import.disabled = true 
2020-11-18 10:40:22,406 [   5550]   INFO - til.net.ssl.CertificateManager - Default SSL context initialized 
2020-11-18 10:40:22,423 [   5567]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2020-11-18 10:40:22,443 [   5587]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=13, fontScale=1.0; restored: fontSize=13, fontScale=1.0 
2020-11-18 10:40:22,480 [   5624]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator) 
2020-11-18 10:40:22,523 [   5667]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryValue - Registry value 'external.system.auto.import.disabled' has changed to 'true' 
2020-11-18 10:40:22,574 [   5718]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\fsnotifier64.exe 
2020-11-18 10:40:22,590 [   5734]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2020-11-18 10:40:23,060 [   6204]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: beta 
2020-11-18 10:40:23,276 [   6420]   INFO - leBasedIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done: 839 
2020-11-18 10:40:23,380 [   6524]   INFO - BridgeProjectLifecycleListener - Using legacy project model to open project 
2020-11-18 10:40:23,677 [   6821]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "ReSharper" not found [Plugin: com.android.tools.ndk] 
2020-11-18 10:40:23,777 [   6921]   WARN - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - Extension to be removed not found: class org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.execution.test.runner.TestClassGradleConfigurationProducer 
2020-11-18 10:40:23,792 [   6936]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Initialization done: 509 
2020-11-18 10:40:23,962 [   7106]   INFO - eStyle.CommonCodeStyleSettings - Loaded XML common code style settings 
2020-11-18 10:40:23,993 [   7137]   INFO - rojectCodeStyleSettingsManager - Initialized from default code style settings. 
2020-11-18 10:40:24,009 [   7153]   INFO - eStyle.CustomCodeStyleSettings - Loaded org.jetbrains.android.formatter.AndroidXmlCodeStyleSettings 
2020-11-18 10:40:24,009 [   7153]   INFO - eStyle.CustomCodeStyleSettings - Loaded com.intellij.psi.codeStyle.JavaCodeStyleSettings 
2020-11-18 10:40:24,009 [   7153]   INFO - eStyle.CustomCodeStyleSettings - Loaded com.intellij.psi.formatter.xml.XmlCodeStyleSettings 
2020-11-18 10:40:24,009 [   7153]   INFO - eStyle.CommonCodeStyleSettings - Loaded Java common code style settings 
2020-11-18 10:40:24,009 [   7153]   INFO - eStyle.CommonCodeStyleSettings - Loaded XML common code style settings 
2020-11-18 10:40:24,246 [   7390]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=org.jetbrains.android.compose.AndroidComposeAutoDocumentation) 
2020-11-18 10:40:24,326 [   7470]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.apk.ApkProjectComponent) 
2020-11-18 10:40:24,326 [   7470]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.apk.issues.SetupIssueReporter) 
2020-11-18 10:40:24,781 [   7925]   INFO - artup.AndroidStudioInitializer - Failed to disable 'org.intellij.plugins.intelliLang.inject.groovy.GrConcatenationInjector' 
2020-11-18 10:40:24,801 [   7945]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found 
2020-11-18 10:40:24,822 [   7966]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:40:25,201 [   8345]   WARN - ugins.textmate.TextMateService - Missing builtin bundles, checked: 
C:/Users/jiroldan/AppData/Roaming/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins/textmate/lib/bundles
C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/textmate/lib/bundles 
2020-11-18 10:40:25,225 [   8369]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 126ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2020-11-18 10:40:25,848 [   8992]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.highlighter.KotlinDefaultHighlightingSettingsProvider 
2020-11-18 10:40:26,114 [   9258]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:40:26,251 [   9395]   INFO - penapi.application.Experiments - Experimental features enabled for user: wsl.p9.support, wsl.p9.show.roots.in.file.chooser, inline.browse.button, linux.native.menu, recent.and.edited.files.together, show.create.new.element.in.popup, copy.reference.popup, new.large.text.file.viewer, property.value.inplace.editing, terminal.shell.command.handling 
2020-11-18 10:40:26,544 [   9688]   INFO - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Load external projects data in 110 millis (read time: 77) 
2020-11-18 10:40:26,546 [   9690]   WARN - openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl - ToolWindow icons should be 13x13. Please fix ToolWindow (ID:  Problems View) or icon jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/lib/icons.jar!/general/warning.svg 
2020-11-18 10:40:26,861 [  10005]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:40:26,878 [  10022]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:40:26,879 [  10023]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.apk.ApkWritingAccessProvider) 
2020-11-18 10:40:27,031 [  10175]   INFO - ngd.lsp.ClangDaemonContextImpl - Using clangd from: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\clang\win\clangd.exe 
2020-11-18 10:40:27,151 [  10295]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:40:27,162 [  10306]   INFO - ProjectRootPostStartUpActivity - D:/AST/Fuentes/ANDROID_STUDIO/_Prb_/Borrame/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false 
2020-11-18 10:40:27,162 [  10306]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Post-startup activities under progress took 1231ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 1/1 sluggish 
2020-11-18 10:40:27,181 [  10325]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 3978 ms 
2020-11-18 10:40:27,489 [  10633]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.gradle.notification.GeneratedFileNotificationProvider) 
2020-11-18 10:40:27,511 [  10655]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.apk.editor.notification.ApkReloadNotificationProvider) 
2020-11-18 10:40:27,649 [  10793]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,150 [  12294]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,364 [  12508]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 4136ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 1/4 sluggish, 1/4 very slow 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,385 [  12529]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 6 ms 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,426 [  12570]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Module Maps finished in 30 ms 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,427 [  12571]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loaded 0 module maps in 0 packs for 0 search roots 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,446 [  12590]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols in FAST mode, 0 source files from total 0 project files 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,556 [  12700]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.apk.symbols.DebugSymbolNotifications) 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,635 [  12779]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Module Maps finished in 239 ms 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,638 [  12782]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Header Maps finished in 3 ms 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,646 [  12790]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loaded 0 tables for 0 files (0 project files) 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,646 [  12790]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 source files 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,650 [  12794]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,650 [  12794]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Updating Symbols finished in 2 ms 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,650 [  12794]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 unused headers 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,650 [  12794]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Updating Symbols finished in 0 ms 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,650 [  12794]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Updating Symbols finished in 0 ms 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,650 [  12794]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving modified symbols for 0 files (0 tables of total 0) 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,650 [  12794]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 ms 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,650 [  12794]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saved 0 module maps in 0 packs 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,650 [  12794]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving Module Maps finished in 0 ms 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,733 [  12877]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 8 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,796 [  12940]   INFO - idGradleProjectStartupActivity - Requesting Gradle sync (DataNode<ProjectData> not found for D:/AST/Fuentes/ANDROID_STUDIO/_Prb_/Borrame). 
2020-11-18 10:40:29,830 [  12974]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started full-variants sync with Gradle for project 'Borrame'. 
2020-11-18 10:40:30,160 [  13304]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:40:30,642 [  13786]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_66 
2020-11-18 10:40:30,642 [  13786]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_66 
2020-11-18 10:40:31,191 [  14335]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:40:31,693 [  14837]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:40:44,803 [  27947]   INFO - oject.common.GradleInitScripts - init script file sync.studio.tooling contents "initscript {\n    dependencies {\n        classpath files(['C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Android\\\\Android Studio\\\\plugins\\\\android\\\\lib\\\\android.jar', 'C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Android\\\\Android Studio\\\\plugins\\\\android\\\\lib\\\\android.jar', 'C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Android\\\\Android Studio\\\\lib\\\\kotlin-stdlib-1.3.72.jar'])\n    }\n}\nallprojects {\n    apply plugin: com.android.ide.gradle.model.builder.AndroidStudioToolingPlugin\n}\n" 
2020-11-18 10:40:44,903 [  28047]   INFO - ration.services.NativeServices - Initialized native services in: C:\Users\jiroldan\.gradle\native 
2020-11-18 10:40:44,903 [  28047]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: -Didea.sync.active=true -Porg.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.cid=2200761430300 --init-script C:\Users\jiroldan\AppData\Local\Temp\sync.studio.tooling2.gradle -Djava.awt.headless=true --stacktrace -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.versioned=3 -Pandroid.injected.studio.version=10.4.1.1 -Pandroid.injected.build.model.disable.src.download=true -Pidea.gradle.do.not.build.tasks=false -Dorg.gradle.internal.GradleProjectBuilderOptions=omit_all_tasks --init-script C:\Users\jiroldan\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit1.gradle 
2020-11-18 10:40:50,492 [  33636]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run phased build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.lambda$run$0(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonConnectionException: Could not receive a message from the daemon.
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection.receive(DaemonClientConnection.java:83)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.executeBuild(DaemonClient.java:168)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:148)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:99)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:211)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.runPhasedAction(ProviderConnection.java:172)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:245)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.PhasedActionAwareConsumerConnection.run(PhasedActionAwareConsumerConnection.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.run(ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:87)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.lambda$run$0(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.MessageIOException: Could not read message from '/0.0.0.0:60172'.
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnection.java:94)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection.receive(DaemonClientConnection.java:77)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.io.IOException: Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host.
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.fill(Input.java:148)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.require(Input.java:178)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readVarInt(Input.java:355)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readInt(Input.java:350)
    at org.gradle.internal.serialize.kryo.KryoBackedDecoder.readSmallInt(KryoBackedDecoder.java:127)
    at org.gradle.internal.serialize.DefaultSerializerRegistry$TaggedTypeSerializer.read(DefaultSerializerRegistry.java:142)
    at org.gradle.internal.serialize.Serializers$StatefulSerializerAdapter$1.read(Serializers.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnection.java:81)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host.
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:377)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection$SocketInputStream.read(SocketConnection.java:196)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.fill(Input.java:146)
    ... 33 more
2020-11-18 10:40:50,523 [  33667]   WARN - ues.SyncIssueUsageReporterImpl - Multiple sync failures reported. Discarding: SDK_BUILD_TOOLS_TOO_LOW 
2020-11-18 10:40:50,541 [  33685]   INFO - System.util.ExternalSystemUtil - External project [D:/AST/Fuentes/ANDROID_STUDIO/_Prb_/Borrame] resolution task executed in 20226 ms. 
2020-11-18 10:40:50,541 [  33685]   WARN - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host.

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (20 s 711 ms) 
2020-11-18 10:40:50,603 [  33747]   INFO - roid.tools.ndk.GradleWorkspace - Updating model took 0.031s 
2020-11-18 10:40:50,819 [  33963]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:40:50,935 [  34079]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appFileTypeManager took 15 ms, StudioFlags took 16 ms 
2020-11-18 10:40:51,057 [  34201]   INFO - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Save external projects data in 22 ms 
2020-11-18 10:40:51,136 [  34280]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.scripting.gradle.GradleScriptInputsWatcher$Storage 
2020-11-18 10:40:51,142 [  34286]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.core.script.configuration.utils.ScriptClassRootsStorage 
2020-11-18 10:40:51,158 [  34302]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project (name=Borrame, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=D:\AST\Fuentes\ANDROID_STUDIO\_Prb_\Borrame) ExternalProjectsManager took 16 ms, XDebuggerManager took 16 ms 
2020-11-18 10:40:51,321 [  34465]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:40:52,345 [  35489]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:40:52,847 [  35991]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:40:53,349 [  36493]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:40:53,433 [  36577]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appFileTypeManager took 15 ms 
2020-11-18 10:40:53,465 [  36609]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project (name=Borrame, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=D:\AST\Fuentes\ANDROID_STUDIO\_Prb_\Borrame) RunManager took 16 ms 
2020-11-18 10:41:00,572 [  43716]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:41:01,073 [  44217]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:41:01,575 [  44719]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:41:02,077 [  45221]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:41:02,578 [  45722]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:41:03,079 [  46223]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:41:03,581 [  46725]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:41:04,083 [  47227]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:41:04,584 [  47728]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:41:05,086 [  48230]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:41:05,588 [  48732]   INFO - .script.IdeScriptEngineManager - javax.script.ScriptEngineManager initialized in 248 ms 
2020-11-18 10:41:06,717 [  49861]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:41:10,841 [  53985]   INFO - j.ide.actions.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1 
2020-11-18 10:41:11,104 [  54248]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:41:11,605 [  54749]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:41:12,106 [  55250]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-11-18 10:41:12,138 [  55282]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appVisualizationTool took 16 ms
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried to close Android Studio, remove directory C:\Users\myUser\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.5-bin and restart Android Studio. It downloads again the gradle6.5.zip, creates again the directory and... the error remains :(

Comment: I don't know the reason of the error. Finally I solved it by exporting (File / Manage IDE Settings) the settings of my home computer and importing them in the office computer. I don't understand why the settings were different if I uninstalled cleaning user data in the office. ¿?  :)

Answer (score 0):

Set gradle to a higher version in  `file` > `project structure` > `gradle`